# unordered list-item and anchor borders overflow parent container

Tags: css, html-lists, overflow, border, containers

I have a simple unordered list beside beside two other divs, all 3 contained within a parent container. Here's how it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/f0bz4hc0/1/. If you zoom in, you can see that all 3 have borders around them, but the borders around the list items and the anchors extend beyond the container's bottom border while the two other divs are snug. Why does this happen and how can I fix it so that everything is within the container?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>practice</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
    *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .page{
        width:960px;
        height:300px;
        margin:0 auto;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    .row{
        width:100%;
    }
    .header{
        background-color:black;
        height:40px;
    }
    .logo{
        background-color:orange;
        height:100%;
        width:40px;
        float:left;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .home{
        display: inline-block;
        height:40px;
        width:40px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid cyan;
    }
    .home img{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    ul{
        float:left;
        height:100%;
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        border:1px solid teal;
    }
    a{
        display: inline-block;
        color:white;
        height:40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        border:1px solid orange;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='page'>
        <div class='header row'>
            <div class='logo'></div>
            <div class='home'><img src='house.png' /></div>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use `inline-block` and `float` at the same time...pick one or the other...not both.

Comment: Got it. Removed floats, and went with display:inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the set height on `.header` and make it `inline-block`, you'll see that the borders of on your anchors remain contained in their parent.

```
.header {
  /*height: 40px;*/
  background-color:black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/q5mxbywp/

Comment: That definitely solves the problem, but removing the height on the header gets rid of the orange div floated to the left, and the anchors don't look like they're vertically centered- they seem closer to the bottom, even though there's no padding.

Comment: Fixed the orange div by placing everything on height:100% (which works for some reason), but the anchors not being vertically aligned still bothers me: https://jsfiddle.net/q5mxbywp/6/